# Laravel API Eloquent Where Clause with Vue not working

Tags: sql, laravel, vue.js, eloquent, vuex

My question is, why doesn't my where clause work?
I use a Laravel API for my vue (with vuex) project.

Here's the Controller function

```
    public function specific_client(Request $request) {
            $id = $request->id;
            return JsonResource::collection(
            Measurement::where('client_id', '=',$id)
            ->with(['clients', 'measurement_data'])->get());
    }
```

I also use vuetify, this is how  I get the client_id :

```
<v-select v-model="cnr" :items="clients" item-text="clientnumber" item-value="id" :hint="cnr" solo></v-select>
```

My store.js :

```
        fetchClientMeasurements({commit}, cnr) {
            axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/clientnr", cnr)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response.data.data);
                    console.log(cnr);
                    commit("setMeasurements", response.data.data);
                });
         },
```

My API Route :

```
Route::post('clientnr', [MeasurementController::class, 'specific_client']);
```

When I console log "cnr" I get back the correct ID but I don't get any data back. If I replace $id in the where clause I do get back the correct information. I feel like it is a stupid mistake I made somewhere, but that's what I'm here for.

Comment: I think `axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/clientnr", cnr)` should be `axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/clientnr", {id: cnr})`

Comment: Wow, that makes a lot of sense (I am super tired haha). Thanks alot! If you write it up as answer I'll upvote and set as answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your axios request, you need to label the `id` parameter.

`axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/clientnr", cnr)`

should be

`axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/clientnr", {id: cnr})`